# What does {:d} mean? Strings Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, string, rows, sudoku

I'm practicing for my finals, doing a task where I'm to assign a number to a spot in a row/column system. The suggested method of solving is this:

```
def readOneNumber():
    row = int(input("Row (1-9): "))
    col = int(input("Column (1-9): "))
    num = int(input("The number (1-9): "))     
    print("Position ({:d},{:d}) now contains {:d}".format(row, col, num))
```

So I am specifically asking about the content of the print function. Does the {:d} part just mean a dictionary by the name of (row, col, num)?

**I was wrong in my assumption that this was about dictionaries. It was actually a formatting tool**

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a formatting character. It tells the formatter to treat the argument as an integer number and format it as such. Other valid formatters could be `x` to format it as a hexadecimal number, or `b` for binary, etc.

See the [*Format String Syntax*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), and more specifically, the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> `'d'`
>   Decimal Integer. Outputs the number in base 10.

Each `{...}` part is a slot, and the positional arguments to the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) are slotted in in the same order.

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't actually assign the number to a spot in a system? It just prints a plaintext of the input?

Comment: @Matsern: yes, it's a template string, and the `{..}` parts are slots.